# Prove convergence of series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $$\displaystyle a_n=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}+(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$$

so I divide it into four series $4k, 4k+1, 4k+2, 4k+3$ and I pair for instance $4k, 4k+1$ and $4k+2, 4k+3$ and prove that these two series is convergent and conclude that since 
both series are convergent so the sum of it is also convergent but I'm not sure if it's legall

second series I'm not sure is like this $\displaystyle b_n=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{6}+...$

here I also split it into smaller parts namely $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n-3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}$ and I prove that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}<\frac{1}{n^2} \cdot c $ for some const c so it implies that origin series is convergent or not ?

Comment: Apologies to interrupt but I feel that by splitting the original series into a particular way and prove that the the arranged series converge does not actually show that the original series is convergent. If you are using this attempt, you must show that all possible arrangements of the original series are convergent. (which is not possible to do so). I suggest you try convergence tests such as ratio or limit comparison.

Comment: OK, but I'm afraid these test fail here since we have negative terms too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** Here is an approach.

Recall that, **for $x$ near $0$**, you have by the Taylor series expansion *or* simply by the finite sum of a geometric sequence:
$$
\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^3),
$$

You may then write, as $n$ is great:
$$
\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/3}+(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/3}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}{n^{1/3}}\right)}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/3}}-\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n+3)}{2}}}{n^{2/3}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}\right)
$$ The series $ \displaystyle
\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/3}}$
 is convergent by the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test),  the series $\displaystyle
\sum\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$ is convergent $(4/3>1)$. Since
$$
\left|\sum_{k=2}^{2N}(-1)^{n(n+3)/2}\right|\leq 2, \qquad \left|\sum_{k=2}^{2N+1}(-1)^{n(n+3)/2}\right|\leq 2,\quad N=1,2,3\ldots,
$$ then the series $ \displaystyle
\sum\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n+3)}{2}}}{n^{2/3}}$
 is convergent by the [Dirichlet series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Comment: do you know how to do it without using Taylor series since I'm not allowed to use it yet :(

Comment: You can obtain that formula via the geometric progression formula for sum to infinity, with common ratio -x and first term 1. Note that the magnitude of -x which is |x| must be strictly smaller than 1. Olivier's case is as this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the series $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_m=\sum_{n\in A}(-1)^n\frac{1}{n^{1/3}-1}=\frac{1}{2^{1/3}-1}-\frac{1}{5^{1/3}-1}+\frac{1}{6^{1/3}-1}-\frac{1}{9^{1/3}-1}+\cdots$ $\hspace{.8 in}$and $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}b_m=\sum_{n\in B}(-1)^n\frac{1}{n^{1/3}+1}=-\frac{1}{3^{1/3}+1}+\frac{1}{4^{1/3}+1}-\frac{1}{7^{1/3}+1}+\frac{1}{8^{1/3}+1}-\cdots$,

$\hspace{.4 in}$where $A=\{n\in\mathbb{N}, n\equiv1 \text{ or } n\equiv2 \pmod 4 \ \text { and } n> 1\}$ and

$\hspace{.8 in}B=\{n\in\mathbb{N}, n\equiv3 \text{ or } n\equiv4 \pmod 4 \}$.

Then both series converge by the Alternating Series Test; so if we let

$(T_m), (U_m), \text{ and }(S_m)$ be the partial sums for $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_m, \displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} b_m$, and the given series, respectively,

then $T_m\to T$ and $U_m\to U$ for some numbers $T$ and $U$.

Since  $S_{2m}=T_m+U_m$ for every $m$, $\;\;S_{2m}\to T+U$;

and since $S_{2m+1}=S_{2m}+\frac{1}{(2m+2)^{1/3}\pm1}, \;\;S_{2m+1}\to T+U$.

Therefore $S_m\to T+U$, and the series converges.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you know what about my series $b_n$ ?

Comment: Your series $\sum b_n$, which is a rearrangement of the alternating harmonic series, diverges.